# Form input-field is too small using Materialize-CSS

Tags: css, materialize

I have a Login form for a basic Admin Portal, however the input-field itself to click on is extremely small. The bar itself seems to be the entire size of the clickable input-field, so you can't click the label whatsoever to enter.

Code as follows:

```
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="white">
        <h5 className="center">Cars4U Administration</h5>
        <div className="input-field">
          <input type="text" name="username" className="validate" required onChange={handleChange} />
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field">
          <input type="password" name="password" className="validate" required onChange={handleChange} />
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div className="input-field center">
          <button className='btn z-depth-0' type='submit'>Login</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

If my cursor is in the following position, I am unable to click the input-field. I am only able to click it directly on the line:

[image]

CSS:

```
form {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-right: 350px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

form label {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

form .input-field {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your code here so we can help debug. What I'm guessing is the input field is too small or has too much padding on it, obscuring the clickable area.

Comment: I added everything that remotely pertained to the field, but also if I remove all of that the field is still working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Anthony's suggestion, you're supposed to have both `name` and `id` as identifiers.

> Add **id** to your input -
>
> `<input name="username"/>` to `<input  name="username"id="username"/>`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <form className="white">
          <h5 className="center">Cars4U Administration</h5>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field">
              <input type="text" id="username" className="validate" required />
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
            </div>
            <div className="input-field">
              <input
                type="password"
                id="password"
                className="validate"
                required
              />
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="input-field center">
            <button className="btn z-depth-0" type="submit">
              Login
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Also the the active label will not remain color coded for validation. As is as soon as I click on another field the label will go back from red to grey. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to have both, as the `name` is the identifier used when passing the form data from the browser to the server.

Comment: It's because you have it as required, you can validate it in a function `onClick`, and highlight fields that you need to highlight for errors.